# Xlib. DisplayWidth does not update as screen resolution does

Tags: x11, display, resolution

`DisplayWidth(Display, DefaultScreen(Display))` does not change its return value even when the monitor changes. I am in a VM and as I resize the monitor, the DisplayWidth and DisplayHeight remains the same. Is there a way to update it with the monitor? I could not find any X function to trigger this update, so is there a more hidden one?